# liquid crystal and light

Tags: physical-chemistry, liquid-crystals

The liquid crystal can be control using polarizes light. This means we can control the arrangement of the liquid crystal molecules, then when the light passes through it can be manipulated.

But why exactly is this possible? What is the relationship between liquid crystal material and light pass through it? How do they interact and affect each other?

Comment: Please check your English grammar. It very unclear who controls what.

Comment: And you don't want to use the word "control" anyway. Look it up in a dictionary, it's a total misapplication, resp. bad labslang.

Comment: [Cross posted on Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/588102/liquid-crystal-and-light) (where it probably belongs anyway).  Suggest closing here.

Comment: This text is not English. A liquid crystal cannot be "controlled". Furthermore, nobody can "control" an arrangement, with or without polarized light. And this arrangement cannot be "manipulated".

Answer (score 2):

**Liquid crystals are controlled by electric fields and their structure manipulates the polarisation of light**

Liquid Crystals are usually made from long rod-shaped molecules which behave in some ways like liquids (they flow) but in other ways like crystals (they form structures with a lot of regularity). The name is appropriate.

The key features that matter are that the structures they form are easy to manipulate with electrical fields and that the rod-like nature of the structure interacts with light in roughly the same way as polaroid: it selectively alters the polarisation of the light passing through.

In LCD devices the liquid crystals are placed between two polaroid filters and in front of a backlight so the the default orientation of the filters plus the liquid crystal layer lets most light through. When a small electric field is applied across the liquid crystal it can be arranged so that it *changes* the orientation of the molecules in the layer and *twists* the light so it no longer passes through the polaroid layers. This can be arranged to happen one pixel at a time with suitable electronics. So an electrical field can drive a display.

That's the basic principle. Real displays have evolved to have some very complex arrangements of these effects to improve speed and the twistiness of the LC layer to make faster responding and higher contrast pixels.